# Very slow performance of cusparse csrsv_analysis

Tags: cuda, linear-algebra, sparse-matrix

I wrote a Conjugate-gradient solver (for linear system of equations) with LU preconditioning, I used Dr. Maxim Naumov's [papers](https://developer.nvidia.com/sites/default/files/akamai/cuda/files/psts_white_paper_final.pdf) on nvidia's research community as a guideline, the residuals update step, which requires solving a lower triangular matrix system and then solving an upper triangular matrix system is divided into two phases:

1. analysis phase (which exploits the sparsity pattern and decides the parallelization level).
2. the solution phase itself.

according to all posts related to this topic, and to Naumov's paper itself, the analysis phase is significantly slower than the solve phase, but it's executed once, so it's not supposed to be an issue when taking the whole execution time in consideration, however, in my program, the analysis phase requires ~35-45% of the whole solution time (time needed to perform all iterations!), which is quite annoying, another thing is that I'm quite sure that the matrix's sparsity pattern doesn't allow a big deal of parallelization, as nearly all elements require previous elements to be known (because in CFD each node will need at least the adjacent 6 nodes (hexahedral volumes) around it, and that's repeated on every row), so the analysis phase won't be very useful anyways !

***matrixLU*** in this code contains both the upper and lower triangular matrices, the upper triangular matrix uses the original matrix diagonals, and the lower triangular matrix has unity diagonals (LU factorization).

```
// z = inv(matrixLU)*r
cusparseMatDescr_t descrL = 0 ;
cusparseMatDescr_t descrU = 0 ;
cusparseStatus = cusparseCreateMatDescr(&descrL) ;
cusparseStatus = cusparseCreateMatDescr(&descrU) ;

cusparseSetMatType(descrL,CUSPARSE_MATRIX_TYPE_GENERAL) ;
cusparseSetMatIndexBase(descrL,CUSPARSE_INDEX_BASE_ONE) ;
cusparseSetMatDiagType(descrL,CUSPARSE_DIAG_TYPE_UNIT) ;
cusparseSetMatFillMode(descrL,CUSPARSE_FILL_MODE_LOWER) ;

cusparseSetMatType(descrU,CUSPARSE_MATRIX_TYPE_GENERAL) ;
cusparseSetMatIndexBase(descrU,CUSPARSE_INDEX_BASE_ONE) ;
cusparseSetMatDiagType(descrU,CUSPARSE_DIAG_TYPE_NON_UNIT) ;
cusparseSetMatFillMode(descrU,CUSPARSE_FILL_MODE_UPPER) ;

cusparseSolveAnalysisInfo_t inforL = 0 ;
cusparseSolveAnalysisInfo_t inforU = 0 ;
cusparseStatus = cusparseCreateSolveAnalysisInfo(&inforL) ;
cusparseStatus = cusparseCreateSolveAnalysisInfo(&inforU) ;

double startFA = omp_get_wtime() ;
cusparseStatus = cusparseDcsrsv_analysis(cusparseHandle, CUSPARSE_OPERATION_NON_TRANSPOSE, N, NZ, descrL, matrixLU, iRow, jCol, inforL) ;
if(cusparseStatus != CUSPARSE_STATUS_SUCCESS) printf("%s \n\n","cusparseDcsrsv_analysis1 Error !") ;
cusparseStatus = cusparseDcsrsv_analysis(cusparseHandle, CUSPARSE_OPERATION_NON_TRANSPOSE, N, NZ, descrU, matrixLU, iRow, jCol, inforU) ;
if(cusparseStatus != CUSPARSE_STATUS_SUCCESS) printf("%s \n\n","cusparseDcsrsv_analysis2 Error !") ;
double finishFA = omp_get_wtime() ;
```

So, anybody got a clue why the analysis phase is so slow ? and how it may be accelerated ? is the (analysis phase execution time)/(solve phase execution time) **ratio** GPU dependent ?

**Edit:**
I tried this solver for many cases, and the results were close, but in the specific case I'm concerned about, it has the following conditions:

- Size (***N***) : ~**860,000 * 860,000**
- Number of non zeros (***NZ***): ~**6,000,000**
- Number of iterations required for convergence: **10**
- **Analysis** phase execution time: **210 ms**
- **Solve** phase executions time (summing up **all iterations**): **350 ms**
- All floating point operations are performed in **double precision** format
- GPU: **GeForce GTX 550 Ti**
- OS: **Windows 7** ultimate, **64 bit**

Comment: What are the problem sizes, GPU and operating system you are running this code on?

Comment: @talonmies, I added the info in the edit, thanks alot for your concern, is anything else required to build the big picture ? I've been struggling with this for days !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I contacted our linear algebra libraries team at NVIDIA and they provided the following feedback.

1. With respect to the performance results:

   1. The CG iterative method performs only 10 iterations until the solution of the linear system is found. It seems that in this case this is not enough iterations to ammortize the time consumed by the analysis phase. **(Edit:)** The number of steps required to converge to the solution varies across different applications. In some unpreconditioned iterative methods do not converge (or take thousands of iterations) and preconditioned iterative methods take tens (or hundreds) of iterations to converge to a solution. The fact that in this particular application the iterative method converges in 10 iterations is not necessarily representative of all applications.
   2. The ratio of the analysis and solve phases is 6 = 210/35, which is in line with our experiments on other matrices, where it is usually in the interval [4,10]. It is not clear how the time for the analysis and solve phases compares to the time taken by the sparse triangular solve on the CPU. (This would be interesting information to know.)
2. With respect to the algorithm:

   1. Unfortunately, there are only a few things you can do to recover a little bit of performance (there is no real way to speed up the analysis phase). For example, you can split the matrixLU into separate lower and upper triangular parts. Computing with separate triangular parts is in general faster than computing with triangular parts embedded in a general matrix. If you are using incomplete factorization with 0 fill-in as a preconditioner, you can also take advantage of the incomplete-LU/Cholesky with 0 fill-in on the GPU, that has recently become available in the CUSPARSE library. (**Edit:**) The incomplete-LU factorization with 0 fill-in is available in CUDA Toolkit 5.0 release. Currently the early access version of this release can be obtained by [registered developers](http://www.nvidia.com/content/cuda/cuda-toolkit.html) on the NVIDIA website.
   2. We have never looked at how the ratio of analysis and solve phases varies across different GPUs; all our experiments done were on C2050.
   3. The analysis phase is slow because it has to collect information on which rows can be processed together into levels. The solve phase is faster because it only processes the levels (See [this paper](http://research.nvidia.com/publication/parallel-solution-sparse-triangular-linear-systems-preconditioned-iterative-methods-gpu)).

Finally, you also mentioned that you think there is not enough parallelism in the problem. But the amount of parallelism can be hard to guess just from looking at the matrix. If indeed there is little parallelism (every row depends on the previous row), then the CUSPARSE sparse triangular solve might not be the right algorithm for this problem. Also, you can try to run the CG iterative method without preconditioning or with other types of preconditioners that might be more suitable to your problem.

As mentioned earlier, it would be interesting to know how the performance of this code compares on the GPU and CPU.

**Edit:**
Regarding some comments... As mentioned earlier the ultimate number of iterations for a preconditioned iterative method varies across different applications. In some cases it can be very small (for example, 10 as it is in your application), but in others it can be relatively large (measured in 100s). The paper focuses not on the “triumph”, but rather the tradeoffs of the algorithm. It attempts to give the user a deeper understanding of the routine in order for it to be used effectively. Again, if the sparsity pattern at hand does not have any parallelism, this is not the right algorithm for you.

With respect to the CPU and GPU comparisons, there are certain problems (such as dense matrix-matrix or sparse matrix-vector multiplication) for which GPU is great, there are others (such as traversing a linked list or executing a completely sequential piece of code) for which it is not. The solution of sparse triangular linear systems lies somewhere in between those algorithms (depending on the sparsity pattern of the coefficient matrix and other properties of the linear system it might or not work well for you). Also, the decision to use the GPU is not based solely on a single algorithm, such as sparse triangular solve, but on the entire set of algorithms used by the application. Ultimately, GPUs are often very successful in accelerating and improving the performance of the overall application.

Finally, with respect to trsm vs. csrsv, it does not surprise us that for small matrices performing operations in dense storage is faster than in sparse storage (even though these small matrices might be sparse). This would usually be true not only for triangular solve, but for other linear algebra operations as well (it might happen at different cross points depending on the operation and the sparsity pattern of the matrix, though). Also, once again, the sparse triangular solve algorithm was designed to run in an iterative setting where the analysis is done once and solve done multiple times. So, it is not surprising that running it once (and counting in the analysis phase), results in a higher crossover point for this operation to be more effective in sparse rather than in dense format.

Comment: First of all, I'd like to thank you for your comprehensive answer, I've been impatiently waiting for this. Let me reply to you point by point as you did:

   1.1. The point of using the LU or Cholesky preconditioning is minimizing the number of iterations, so the fewer number of iterations is a feature of the preconditioning and the solver should be optimized for such cases.

Comment: 1.2. I'm already bench marking my code against many powerful CPU versions (MKL, and other codes written in our company), the diagonal scaling preconditioned version of the CG was faster on GPU, while the LU preconditioned version was much slower.

Comment: 2.1. I read Dr. naumov's paper (http://research.nvidia.com/publication/parallel-incomplete-lu-and-cholesky-factorization-preconditioned-iterative-methods-gpu) which describes how to construct the LU or Cholesky factorization, but according to the latest documentation of cUSparse, there's no function to create the preconditioner, but please let me know if there's, It would be really helpful.

Comment: 2.2. It would be great to make such test and publish them.

Comment: 2.3. I don't understand how would Dr. Maxim consider the speed up of the solve phase over MKL a triumph if he's using a 1300 $ Tesla C2050 against a 300 $ intel i7 950, I guess the comparison is unfair, besides, the speedup gain is acquired if the solve phase is repeated multiple times, which can be high in some cases, while the preconditioning is usually required to reduce the number of iterations

Comment: So overall, I'm very interested in the following points:
1. is the Cholesky factorization now available in CuSparse ? which version ?
2. the diagonal scaling CG on GPU outperformed the CPU versions, while the LU & Cholesky versions were much slower, exclusively due to the analysis phase.
3. I'll give it a try with non preconditioned CG instead of triangular solver, and I'll let you know what happened.
Thanks in advance @harrism

Comment: I will ask Maxim for further comments (he doesn't have an SO account), but to your perf/$ comparison comment. Tesla C2050 is an HPC-class processor that includes SSE RAM on board. Intel i7 is a consumer-class CPU that contains no ram.  To do a fair price comparison you would need to include the cost of SSE RAM, if not a Xeon (HPC-class) CPU. This would be much more than $300.

Comment: Among all CPU versions of the CG that I've tried for our problems, the LU preconditioned version was the fastest, the LU version on CPU is faster than the diagonal scaling version on GPU, so I'm interested in using CUDA to write an LU preconditioned CG solver, I keep wondering if there's a way to simply skip the analysis phase or tell it to pass a default one-leveled info structure ?

Comment: I'm basically bench-marking the GTX 550 Ti against an intel i7 950, as I mentioned before, the diagonal scaling preconditioned CG was faster on GPU rather than CPU, it was even slightly slower than a Xeon X5680 !
So, we're very interested in using Tesla GPUs, but I firstly need to find a way to accelerate the LU preconditioned CG algorithm.

Comment: I have added edits above. Here are some questions?  1.2: what is the actual performance you achieve?

Comment: @harrism It has been 18 months since this issue was raised. CUDA 5.0 is out and CUSPARSE is generally available. However, I cannot identify a comprehensive resource -- a high-level library, for example -- addressing GPU sparse solvers. What is the current (almost 2014) state of those codes?