# cuSparse vs. cuBlas triangular solvers

Tags: cuda, linear-algebra, sparse-matrix, cublas

Actually I posted a relevant question a few days ago, but I got zeros answers, however, I came to a very strange finding yesterday, as  mentioned in my previous question: [Very slow performance of cusparse csrsv_analysis](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11382346/1501149), the analysis phase of the sparse triangular solver of cusparse is annoyingly slow, not to mention it's sometimes unnecessary when the coefficients matrix sparsity pattern doesn't allow parallelization, so I wanted to see how cublas dense triangular solver would handle that, so I replaced the cusparse solver with a cublas solver after converting my coefficients matrix to dense format, and the cublas verions was ~7x faster than the cusparse version given the same matrix and even after including the matrix format conversion time in CuBlas solver ! I revised the solution so it's correct in both cases !

**CuSparse version**

```
// Analysis phase   
cusparseStatus = cusparseDcsrsv_analysis(cusparseHandle, CUSPARSE_OPERATION_NON_TRANSPOSE, N, NZ, descrL, matrixLU, iRow, jCol, inforL) ;
if(cusparseStatus != CUSPARSE_STATUS_SUCCESS) printf("%s \n\n","cusparseDcsrsv_analysis1 Error !") ;
cusparseStatus = cusparseDcsrsv_analysis(cusparseHandle, CUSPARSE_OPERATION_NON_TRANSPOSE, N, NZ, descrU, matrixLU, iRow, jCol, inforU) ;
if(cusparseStatus != CUSPARSE_STATUS_SUCCESS) printf("%s \n\n","cusparseDcsrsv_analysis2 Error !") ;

// Solve phase  
cusparseStatus = cusparseDcsrsv_solve(cusparseHandle, CUSPARSE_OPERATION_NON_TRANSPOSE, N, &c2, descrL, matrixLU, iRow, jCol, inforL, r, t) ;
if(cusparseStatus != CUSPARSE_STATUS_SUCCESS) printf("%s \n\n","cusparseDcsrsv_solve1 Error !") ;
cusparseStatus = cusparseDcsrsv_solve(cusparseHandle, CUSPARSE_OPERATION_NON_TRANSPOSE, N, &c2, descrU, matrixLU, iRow, jCol, inforU, t, z) ;
if(cusparseStatus != CUSPARSE_STATUS_SUCCESS) printf("%s \n\n","cusparseDcsrsv_solve2 Error !") ;
```

**CuBlas version**

```
// CSR to dense conversion
cusparseStatus = cusparseDcsr2dense(cusparseHandle, N, N, descrLU, matrixLU, iRow, jCol, aLU, N) ; 
if(cusparseStatus != CUSPARSE_STATUS_SUCCESS) printf("%s \n\n","cusparseDcsr2dense1 Error !") ;

// Solving directly
cublasStatus = cublasDtrsv(cublasHandle, CUBLAS_FILL_MODE_LOWER, CUBLAS_OP_N, CUBLAS_DIAG_UNIT, N, aLU, N, z, 1) ;
if(cublasStatus != CUBLAS_STATUS_SUCCESS) printf("%s \n\n","cublasSolve1 Error !") ;
cublasStatus = cublasDtrsv(cublasHandle, CUBLAS_FILL_MODE_UPPER, CUBLAS_OP_N, CUBLAS_DIAG_NON_UNIT, N, aLU, N, z, 1) ;
if(cublasStatus != CUBLAS_STATUS_SUCCESS) printf("%s \n\n","cublasSolve2 Error !") ;
```

Test case:

- Size (N) = **5000 * 5000**
- Number of non zeros (NZ) = **35,000**
- Number of iterations: **3**
- CuSparse solution time, analysis phase executed once: **180 ms**
- CuBlas solution time: **30 ms**
- GPU: **GeForce GTX 550 Ti**
- OS: **Windows 7 ultimate, 64 bit**

Of course, using CuBlas is impractical for me, since my work involves large dimensions matrices, starting from 100,000 and even reaching 1,000,000, and so, memory allocation of such sizes is simply impractical, so is there a way to start the sparse solver without the analysis phase ?

Comment: Be patient, sometimes answers take time. I answered your previous question tonight. This really should have been an edit on your first question...

Comment: I apologize guys, I just thought the first question went in vain, yet you proved me wrong, besides, I thought the cuBlas comparison finding is worthy of a new question. I read your first answer @harrism and it's quite comprehensive, however, I have no idea how would cuBlas be faster than cuSparse for sparse matrices, I'll wait for your comments on that, sincere thanks.

Comment: Well, if I understand correctly, you are converting to a dense matrix, and cuBLAS is faster at that. I think the answer to the other question should answer this one to some extent too, especially if you provide the additional info requested on the other question.

Comment: I disagree with you, cuSparse was written to accelerate the sparse matrix operations, and converting a certain sparse matrix to dense format and then using cuBLAS should definitely be slower, cuSparse is more efficient when sparse matrices are involved

Comment: You aren't exactly making me want to help... :)  Have you considered that there is probably a matrix size threshold below which a simpler dense computation is more efficient on the hardware? Sparse matrix linear algebra is much more memory bound than dense matrix algebra. The memory access patterns are not as friendly to parallel processors.

Comment: @harrism, I really appreciate your to-the-point answers & comments, so I apologize if I unintentionally said something that makes you "not wanting to help", hope you'd clarify whether you meant my last comment was so shallow or what ? :)
All I wanted to say is that a **25,000,000** elements matrix containing only **35,000** non-zeros must be performing plenty of unnecessary operations when using cuBlas, and if these operations are omitted by using sparse memory patterns, they would get faster, that's all I meant, but you sure have a point concerning the parallelization issues of such patterns.