# How to accelerate preconditioned conjugate gradient using cusparse?

Tags: cuda

I am working on a CFD project and I am using the new CUDA 5 libary "cusparse" to solve a system of linear equations. I tested the sample code "conjugateGradientPrecond". The result show that Preconditioned Gradient using ILU took more time to get the final answer than Conjugate gradient without preconditioning. The former algorithm do need less iteration, but it take to much time on "cusparseScsrsv_solve", so the overall time is longer.

Here is my question, is there any other preconditioned conjugate Gradient that can greatly decrease the iteration while don't include any time-consuming function like "cusparseScsrsv_solve"?

Answer (score 1):

Preconditioning techniques such as ILU0/ILUT, IC0/ICT will require to solve a triangular system two times at each iteration of CG (upper and lower decomposition of the preconditioning matrix). By nature, solving triangular systems is a sequential problem, but for case of sparse matrices some analysis phase can be performed to find some degrees of parallelization (refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11382346/very-slow-performance-of-cusparse-csrsv-analysis)). In general, for sparse systems, one can not offer the best preconditioning technique, but the simple diagonal (aka Jacobi) preconditioning, imposes negligible overhead and offers high level of parallelization for GPU implementation.